# Python GObject Introspection for Windows 7

Tags: python, windows, matplotlib, gobject, gobject-introspection

I am trying to use `matplotlib` in Python but any imports fail with the following error:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_gtk3cairo import FigureCanvasGTK3Cairo as FigureCanvas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_gtk3cairo.py", line 6, in <module> 
from . import backend_gtk3
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_gtk3.py", line 21, in <module>
    "Gtk3 backend requires the GObject introspection bindings for Gtk 3 "
ImportError: Gtk3 backend requires the GObject introspection bindings for Gtk 3 to be installed.
```

The application needs to be able to run on Windows machines. Does anyone have any support on this?

I have found a lot of old threads that say it is impossible to use `GTK3` and Python on Windows, but they are at least 2-3 years old. So things might have changed since then.

Comment: No one is compiling gtk3 with matplotlib under Windows? Need some help here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by using the pygi-aio installer from `http://sourceforge.net/projects/pygobjectwin32/files/pygi-aio-3.14.0_rev22-setup.exe` and uninstalling any other older dependencies (GTK2, pygobject, etc)